# ¿Es posible hacer enumeraciones dinámicas C#?

Tags: c#, enum

Quisiera saber si es posible modificar los miembros de una enum desde una clase derivada (añadir o quitar miembros dinamicamente).

```
public class Base 
{ 
    public enum MyEmum { none, case1, case2, case3, ...., caseN };
    public MyEmum myEmum;
}

public class Derivada : Base 
{ 
    public ModificaEnum()
   { 
         //algo asi sería genial
         Base.MyEmum.Add(nuevo_miembro);
         Base.MyEmum.Remove(viejo_miembro);
    }

}
```

Comment: Esto, no tiene ningun sentido... un Enum es una estructura que se usa para controles... porque querrias hacer algo asi?

Comment: pasate por el [chat].. creo que podran ayudarte mas...

Comment: Tiene sentido si consigo hacer o emular un swich donde pueda añadir o quitar casos... de hecho ya casi lo tengo... poder hacer esto con un enum sería genial... y si no se puede habrá que buscar una alternativa que encaje con el swith

Comment: Seria de gran ayuda si agregas en pseudocodigo, para que quieres el switch y enum.

Comment: Me hicieron separar todas mis preguntas... el enum lo quiero porque son los posibles casos del swich... y aqui puedes ver todo lo referente al el swtch https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/421561/es-posible-a%c3%b1adir-casos-a-un-swich-de-forma-din%c3%a1mica-en-tiempo-de-ejecuci%c3%b3n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es posible agregar elementos en tiempo de ejecución a un enum. El termino `enum` indica enumeración, que se pueden contar o dimensionar la cantidad de elementos existentes en la entidad.

[Como te mencione en una respuesta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/421551/38468), utiliza `Dictionary<Key,Value>` que puede satisfacer tu necesidad de almacenar valores y propiedades dinamicas.

Comment: Gracias Einer!!