# ¿Es posible hacer estructuras dinámicas C#?

Tags: c#, class, estructuras

Quisiera saber si es posible modificar los miembros de una estructura o clase desde una clase derivada (añadir o quitar miembros dinamicamente)

```
public class Base 
{ 
    public struct MyStruct
    {
        public Type originalVar;
    }
    MyStruct myStruct;
}

public class Derivada : Base 
{ 
    public ModificaEnum()
   { 
         //algo asi sería genial
         MyStruct.Add(Type, nuevaVar);
         MyStruct.Remove(Type, originalVar);
    }

}
```

Comment: La pregunta seria.. para que? si es una estructura, todos quienes la usen van a necesitar saber que tiene.. entonces, que sentido tendria?

Comment: Si tienes que recurrir a este tipo de prácticas en una clase derivada es que el diseño necesita ser replanteado

Comment: La quiero usar como plantilla... es decir, es una estructura que debe existir y debe ser implementada desde la clase derivada....aunque tambien la uso desde la clase base... en C++ se hace algo parecido con las funciones... "funciones virtuales" ...

Comment: Las funciones virtuales de C++ no son de quita y pon. Lo que puedes hacer con ellas es modificar su comportamiento en las clases derivadas. Eso lo puedes hacer también en c# ([ejemplo](http://www.nachocabanes.com/csharp/curso2015/csharp07c.php))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Y que tal si utilizas clases que estan hechos para eso como los `Dictionary`? Estas te permiten agregar/actualizar/eliminar cualquier propiedad(indexador en este caso) sin tener que generar codigo en tiempo de ejecucion:

```
var data = new Dictionary<String,object>();
data.Add("nombre", "Martin");
data.Add("edad", 16);

int edad = (int)data["edad"];
Console.WriteLine(edad);
```

Tambien existe el tipo `dynamic` utilizando la clase `ExpandoObject` en c#:

```
dynamic p = new ExpandoObject();
p.nombre = "Einer";
p.edad = 99;

Console.WriteLine(p.nombre);
Console.WriteLine(p.edad.GetType().Name); // Int32
```

Generar propiedades en tiempo de ejecucion es muy costo asi que deberias evitarlo. Recuerda que c# es un lenguaje tipado y agregarle la funcionadad de chequeo de tipos en tiempo de ejecucion puede costarte.

Comment: Me gusta!! muchas gracias por tu respuesta!! ¿Se puede acceder de alguna forma al diccionario usando un indice númerico?

Comment: @IvánRodríguez Los diccionarios no son vectores. Se ordenan en base a su clave. Puedes recorrerlos usando iteradores, eso sí, pero no índices numéricos

Comment: Gracias eferion!!