# ¿Es posible añadir casos a un swich de forma dinámica (en tiempo de ejecución)? C#

Tags: c#, switch

Me pregunto si es posible añadir casos a un switch de en tiempo de ejecución. Es decir, empezar con un switch vacio como el siguiente:

```
switch (opcion)
        {
            default:
                 break;
        }
```

Y luego añadir casos si es necesario

```
switch (opcion)
        {
            case Case1:
                {
                  break;
                }

                .....
                .....
                .....
            case CaseN:
                {

                    break;
                }
            default:
                 break;
        }
```

Decir que he hecho un código que "emula" (mas o menos) lo que quiero hacer y es el siguiente:

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------
public class DinamicSwith<T> where T : IComparable
{
    public delegate T Delegate();
    public List<Delegate> caseList;
    public List<T> option;
    public Delegate Default;
    T defaultReturn;
    bool isDefaultSet;

    public DinamicSwith(T defaultReturn)
    {
        caseList = new List<Delegate>();
        option = new List < T >();
        this.defaultReturn = defaultReturn;
    }
    public void AddCase(Delegate func, T option)
    {        
        caseList.Add(func);
        this.option.Add(option);
    }
    public void AddDefault(Delegate func)
    {
        Default = func;
        isDefaultSet = true;
    }
    public T Execute(T option)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < caseList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (this.option[i].CompareTo(option)==0)
            {
                return caseList[i]();
            }
        }

        if(isDefaultSet)    
            Default();

        return defaultReturn;
    }
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Lo que quiero saber es si hay alguna forma de hacerlo "por defecto"... es decir, un método que te proporcione el propio lenguaje C# (una forma mas simple y eficiente). Gracias!!

Comment: Podrías explicar que uso le darías a algo asi? Por cierto, interesante tu solución al problema :)

Comment: Lo quiero para hacer una clase Base.... tengo un montón de classes con la misma estructura, todas se basan en un swich pero todas tienen diferentes casos... lo que quiero es consevar la estructura y los valores devueltos y no tener que volver escribir toda la estructura una y otra vez... así reduzco los posibles errores que pueda cometer (o al menos esa es la idea)

Comment: Ivan..lo que describes se parece muy sospechosamente a un [interfaz](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface). Seguro que no es lo buscas?

Comment: me resulta interesante puedes comentar sobre el objetivo de esta implementacion...

Comment: Pues no lo sé la verdad... No estoy muy familiarizado con C#... Este lenguaje es muy diferente a C++ que es el que mas o menos controlo... Me informaré sobre como funcionan las interfaces a ver si esose ajusta a lo que busco...

Comment: Las interfaces son una especie de plantilla que pueden heredar las clases. Te recomiendo efectivamente que le eches un vistazo a ver si encaja con lo que buscas, porque la idea de un switch dinamico a mi personalmente me parece muy extraña :)

Comment: Si Franciasco, en el segundo comentario se lo explico a Pikoh.... no sé si quieres mas detalles... en mi primer post habia puesto todo el código y explicaba todo lo que quería hacer pero la gente empezó a tirarme los trastos a la cabeza porque decian que era demasiado jejeje... al final lo terminé borrando y simplificando las preguntas al máximo...

Comment: Les daré un vistazo... Gracias Pikoh!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Realmente lo que estás haciendo es un *mapa*, en pseudo código sería algo así:

```
Map<Case, Function> switch = ...
Function fun;
if (switch.hasKey(myCase)) {
    fun = switch.get(MyCase);

} else {
    fun = switch.get(DEFAULT);
}
fun(...);
```

En cualquier momento podrías añadir nuevos "casos", asociados a una nueva función. Esto se podría hacer en cualquier lenguaje de programación.
Y realmente los switch se suelen transformar al compilar a una tabla hash para no tener que ir comparando caso por caso y que cualquier entrada se resuelva en O(1), sin importar cuantos casos hay (tu implementación recorre todos hasta que encuentra el que se cumple).

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta Pablo!!

Comment: @IvánRodríguez dado que esta respuesta te parece util, te dejo un enlace a su versión _pura_ en C# : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33107026/dynamic-switch-cases/33107219#33107219

Comment: Muchas Gracias Pikoh!!